# How to make PJAX work with Express and EJS?

Tags: javascript, express, pjax

Okay,  question from the land of noob. But i've been trying to get pjax to work for a while now and nothing seems to work. 
The best I've gotten has been an acknowledgement of the process in terminal, but when I click the link, it takes me to a whole other page rather than displaying its content in a specified div.

And I also included a link to Chris Wanstrath's pjax source code.
Nothing seems to work.

```js
//The schedule.js file 
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('schedule', { title: 'Schedule' });
});

//The jQuery end of the line
$(document).pjax('a[data-pjax]', '#pjax-container');
```

```html
 <li><a data-pjax="#pjax-container" href="/schedule">Schedule</a></li>
 
 <div id="pjax-container"> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Maybe try `router.get('/schedule', ...);` ?

Comment: Problem has been solved, but your suggestion didn't work. Tried it  a while back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that pjax can be set up correctly and still reload the page if you send a `<html>` tag in with the payload then it triggers a reload - perhaps when you make a request this is why your page is loading?

Also the default timeout for a failed request to the server is set to about 600ms so in the code below i have upped the default to 5000ms.

You will need to differentiate server side whether the request is for part of the document or the full document using the http header `"X-PJAX"` which pjax appends to the header.

Here is my solution to this using nodejs / express 5 / pjax

create a helper file named `pjax-helper.js` with the following contents

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function() {
    return function pjax( req, res, next ) {
        if( req.header( 'X-PJAX' ) ) {
            req.pjax = true;
            res.locals.pjax = true;
        } else {
            req.pjax = false;
            res.locals.pjax = false;
        }
        next();
    };
};
```

In your app you can then require the file

`var pjax = require('./include/pjax-helper');`

and in once express is loaded...

`app.use(pjax());`

Now you will have the variable available in both your app and your view layer

---

In my case using EJS template engine i did something like this...

```
//schedule.ejs:
<%- include('includes/header') %>
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<%- include('includes/footer') %>
```

--

```
//includes/header.ejs
<% if(locals.pjax==false) { %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> ... </head>
    <body>

        <%- include('menu') %>

        <div id="pjax-container">
<% } %>
```

--

```
//includes/footer.ejs
<% if(locals.pjax==false) { %>
</div><!--/#pjax-ccontainer-->

<script src="/js/pjax.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).pjax('a.pjax', '#pjax-container', {timeout: 5000});
    $(document).on('pjax:send', function() { $('#loading').show(); });
    $(document).on('pjax:complete', function() { $('#loading').fadeOut(); });
</script>

</body>
</html>

<% } %>
```

Comment: Even though I had figured out the answer before I saw yours, 'including' the header and footer did the trick. Especially with the page reloads.

Comment: @Nnanyielugo Glad everything worked out - It would be helpful to others if you could mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: There is also a package to make that easy https://github.com/dakatsuka/express-pjax